# Should the [covid] tag be merged with the [covid-19] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

At the time of writing,  the [covid-19](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19) tag has [160 questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19) and a detailed user guidance, whereas the [covid](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid) tag has only [two questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid) and no guidance.

It seems sensible to merge the latter with the former as a synonym.

Comment: Without a doubt.